# colord-sane crash after boot at startup on Xubuntu 16.04 64-bit

Tags: xubuntu, crash, sane

I'm getting a popup message right after I boot up to the desktop saying the **colord-sane** has crashed, and if I want to send a crash report. I'm sure there must be a log file of this, but I don't know where to look for it to post it on here. In the message I read something about some ppa repositories are not up to date, which I find preposterous. I did do a **sudo apt-get update** in the terminal without any change. The pc seems to work just fine as it is, and all software programs also seem to work just fine too. I'm not sure what this is - a bug or what. Anybody know how I can post the log of this error for further help?

Here is what I have in /var/log/apport.log.1

```
ERROR: apport (pid 1368) Tue Jan 24 17:45:22 2017: called for pid 1091, signal 6, core limit 0
ERROR: apport (pid 1368) Tue Jan 24 17:45:22 2017: executable: /usr/lib/colord/colord-sane (command line "/usr/lib/colord/colord-sane")
ERROR: apport (pid 1368) Tue Jan 24 17:45:23 2017: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 1368) Tue Jan 24 17:45:24 2017: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_lib_colord_colord-sane.112.crash
```

This is about finding a solution to the error about the colord-sane crashing. 
I need someone to walk me thru the steps: 1, 2, 3,... etc. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I recently upgraded my HDD to a SSD and started getting this annoying error. The root cause of this problem, seems to me, is a TIMING ISSUE with "/usr/lib/colord/colord-sane". Particularly when it doesn't happen every time I boot up with my new SSD. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not fix it uninstalling sane-utils and colord.

`sane-backends` release `1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu4` solves this bug as pointed out [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu4):

```
  * debian/patches/kodak_avahi_crash.patch:
    - Fix crash when Avahi fails scanning for Kodak scanners
```

In order to fix it I had to download and install this `sane-backends` release:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/sane-backends_1.0.25+git20150528.orig.tar.gz -O sane.tar.gz
tar -xf sane.tar.gz
cd sane-backends-git20150528
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Finally, reboot. Hope it works for you.

Comment: This worked for me - Had internal error at startup with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS after Ubuntu Update (17 oct 2017) which involved `colord-sane` .

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get remove sane-utils
sudo apt-get remove colord
```

Worked for me, 16.04 running Xfce, but I've no need for color profiles.

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1351286